# Custom Validation causing computed values to fire

Tags: validation, knockout.js

For a quick view of my problem I have made a working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jqueryAustin/cu7jq/1/):

In KnockoutJS I have made a custom extender validator to test if the input format is in the HHMM format. If it is it returns the new value, if it doesn't it will set it back to the old value this is currently working.

```
ko.extenders.acValidTimeHHMM = function (target, options) {
var result = ko.computed({
    read: target, 
    write: function (newValue) {
        var re = /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]$/;
        if (!re.test(newValue)) {
            target.notifySubscribers(target());
            //Time not in correct format return old time
            return;
        }
        target(newValue);
    }
}).extend({ notify: 'always' });

result(target());
return result;
};
```

The problem I am having is that I update my database when the value changes using a computed. However this is also firing when I reset the value back to its original using my validator. (Method based on Ryan Rahlf dirty flag technique [here](http://ryanrahlf.com/creating-a-dirty-flag-in-your-knockout-js-view-model/) )

```
self.update = ko.computed(function () {
    self.timeOne();
    self.timeTwo();
    alert("Fired");
});
```

The problem is obviously the line target.notifySubscribers(target()); in my validator. However without this line I can't reset the value to its old value and I can't find another way to do this.

So this only fires when a value actually changes rather then the validator resetting it. The jsFiddle demonstrates my problem exactly and can be used to make a working version (hopefully) I know its currently firing on page load too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem I am having is that I update my database when the value changes using a computed.

I don't know all your logic, but I don't think this is a good idea to update the db each time your knockout view model has updated. May be you should look at [knockout validation plugin](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation). Using this plugin you can build the same custom validation rule and update the db only on form submit event.

About your problem...
The simplest solution I'm found is to send a success callback function to the validation extension like an option. 
Something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nLJD/).

JS:

```
var ViewModel = function() {  
    var update = function () {
        alert("value was successfully changed");
    };

    var cancel = function () {
        alert("validation failed. previous value was returned");
    };

    var timeOne = ko.observable("1100").
        extend({ 
                    acValidTimeHHMM: { 
                        success: update,
                        fail: cancel
                    }
               });

    var timeTwo = ko.observable("1248").
        extend({ acValidTimeHHMM: { success: update } });

    return {
        timeOne: timeOne,
        timeTwo: timeTwo
    };
};

ko.extenders.acValidTimeHHMM = function(target, option) {    
    var baseOptions = {
        success: null,
        fail: null
    };
    $.extend(baseOptions, option);

    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target, 
        write: function (newValue) {
            var oldValue = target();
            if(newValue == oldValue) return;

            var re = /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]$/;
            if (!re.test(newValue)) {
                target.notifySubscribers(oldValue);
                if(typeof(baseOptions.fail) == "function")
                    baseOptions.fail();
                return;
            }
            target(newValue);

            if(typeof(baseOptions.success) == "function")
                baseOptions.success()
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

    result(target());
    return result;
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

HTML:

```
<p>Time One<input data-bind='value: timeOne' /></p> 
<p>Time Two<input data-bind='value: timeTwo' /></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Max - Your solution has given me a good work around for now. By update the database, I actually just go and grab information based on the input time (this has to be in Real Time) so it needs to be called on successful update.